# Prove that $f$ is homogenous of degree $k$ if and only if $Df(x)x = k f(x)$ for all nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

Prove that $f$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ if and only if $Df(x)x = k f(x)$ for all nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

> Def'n: We say $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}-\{0\}$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ if $f(t\mathbf{x}) = t^{k}f(t\mathbf{x})$ for all non zero $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

For convenience of typing I'm going to just type $x$ instead of $\mathbf{x}$ and it should be understood from context.

I was also provided to assume $f$ is differentiable as well as a **hint:** Fix $\mathbf{x}$ and consider $h(t) = t^{-k}f(tx)$.

**Attempt:**

Supposing that $f$ is  homogeneous of degree $k$.

Using the hint and differentiating $h(t)$ with respect to $t$, I obtain:

$$-kt^{-k-1}f(tx) + t^{-k}f'(tx)x$$

Now if I'm using my assumption properly, since we are assuming $f$ is homogeneous I can write the following:

$$-kt^{-k-1}t^{k}f(x) + t^{-k}t^{k-1}f'(x)x$$

I can say $f'(tx) = t^{k-1}f'(x)$ because differentiation "reduces the exponent by 1".

Assuming this to be true, then simplifying I have:

$$t^{-1}(-kf(x) + f'(x)x) = 0$$

From which I can divide out the $t^{-1}$ and rearranging I will have:

$$f'(x)x = kf(x)$$

Now observe f'(x) = Df(x) so:

$$Df(x)x = kf(x)$$

as we desired.

**Concerns:**

1. Even though the algebra all seemed to work out is this what was expected in the approach?
2. I forgot what was the property that allows me to set the derivative equal to zero when optimizing.

Comment: For 2, notice that you're not really optimizing, rather you're using the fact that $h(t)=f(x)$ is constant in $t$ and therefore has 0 derivative.

Comment: when you say "constant in $t$" you're saying that my function $h$ is dependent on the value of $t$, but since it is defined as $h(t) = f(x)$ it is a constant? ....I'm just trying to wrap my head around the right language being used

Comment: You have a lot of excess... For instance, using @Jose27's comment, you can write $$-kt^{-k-1}f(tx) + t^{-k}f'(tx)x = 0$$ immediately upon differentiating at the top of your solution.  Then you can just set $t=1$ and rearrange to be done.

Comment: Why can I set $t = 1$?, that would be nice

Comment: Both $t \mapsto t^{-k}$ and $t \mapsto f(t\mathbf{x})$ (for a fixed $\mathbf{x}$) are differentiable for $t\neq 0$, hence for $t=1$...

Comment: Hmmm...I would've never considered this step or concept....where did this "thought" come from?

Comment: It's the justification you need to have already considered to use the product rule as you had done.  The point is that you have an equation that holds for all $t\neq 0$ so you can evaluate for any nonzero $t$ you want, of which $t=1$ works best...

Comment: Again one of those small pieces of a statement that often get glossed over when reading comes back to be pivotal......I need to really remind myself to take account of every single phrase in a math statement. Thanks for the help.